# XPath: Cant get the right value out of a selected Tag

Tags: xslt, xpath

this is my first question here on stackoverflow, so please dont kill me.
But lets get right to the problem. I have a given xhtml and need to get specific information out of it.

Here is my xsl file so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"
        omit-xml-declaration="no" />
    <xsl:template match="html">
        <xsl:element name="Speisekarte">
            <xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation"
                namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Speiseplan_Mensa_Schema.xsd</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select=".//table[@class='table module-food-table']">
                <xsl:element name="Speisen">
                    <xsl:element name="namen">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./thead/tr/th[1]" />
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:for-each select="./tbody/tr">
                        <xsl:element name="zutaten">
                            <xsl:value-of select="./td" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="preis">
                            <xsl:element name="Studenten">
                                <xsl:value-of select="./td[2]" />
                            </xsl:element>
                            <xsl:element name="Mitarbeiter">
                                <xsl:value-of select="./td[3]" />
                            </xsl:element>
                            <xsl:element name="Gäste">
                                <xsl:value-of select="./td[4]" />
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My problem is by the element "zutaten". I need to get "Hackbällchen in Rahmsauce" out of this xhtml file:

```
<tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="width:70%">
                      Hackbällchen in <sup>(R)</sup> Rahmsauce <sup>(9,G,A,I)</sup>
                      <div class="price hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                        <span>1,50&nbsp;&euro;</span><span>2,15&nbsp;&euro;</span><span>2,80&nbsp;&euro;</span>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="hidden-xs" style="text-align:center">
                      1,50&nbsp;&euro;
                    </td>
                    <td class="hidden-xs" style="text-align:center">
                      2,15&nbsp;&euro;
                    </td>
                    <td class="hidden-xs" style="text-align:center">
                      2,80&nbsp;&euro;
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
```

I tried:

```
<xsl:value-of select="./td/text()" />
```

which give me this: Hackbällchen in  Rahmsauce 1,50 2,15 € 2,80 €
or i tried:

```
<xsl:value-of select="./td/text()[not(self::div)]" />
```

which give me an error.

And i tried many different things. Can u guys help me with this?
Hope my english was good enough to understand my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A note about style, similar to unnecessary `./` in your XPath. If your element names are static, `xsl:element` and `xsl:attribute` could be replaced with literal element and attribute constructors that are easier to read, as they look like your output. i.e. `<Speisekarte xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Speiseplan_Mensa_Schema.xsd"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">...</Speisekarte>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you want is this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="td[1]/text()" />
```

By doing `td/text()` (the `./` prefix is unnecessary here), you are getting all `td` nodes, and all the text underneath all these nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the predicate on the first column. The XPath `./td` will select ALL of the `td` elements in that row. Using `xsl:value-of` will produce the computed text value of whatever you have selected, which happens to be all of the td elements (to include the `text()` node descendants). You can verify this by changing `xsl:value-of` to `xsl:copy-of`.

If you want just the `text()` from the first `td` column, use `td[1]/text()`.